# How to intelligently enable/disable user interface controls in a Windows winform or webform?

Tags: asp.net, windows, webforms

If I have a Windows winform with many controls that should be selectively enabled or disabled, depending on the current stage of the program, is there a better way to accomplish this than by adding a click event handler to each such control and then, one by one, adding enabling/displaying code for every other control whose state needs to be tweaked?  This leads to an excessive amount of such statements sprinkled throughout the application. It looks so ugly. Is it possible to build a finite state machine beforehand, with all the proper states, events, code execution, and next states for each event that needs to be handled, and get the appropriate event handler invoked **automatically** simply by virtue of the fact that a control is a pushbutton, checkbox, radio button, dropdown box, etc?

Is there some other smart way to accomplish this?  Should I just rewrite this as a webform and respond to the top-level click event for the whole webform?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, to use web based forms and windows forms in the same question?

The difference is like that of a cat, and a mountain. They are VERY different.

So, in web land?

Just drop the controls you want to hide/show inside of a div, and then show/hide that div.

So, say this for asp.net:

```
<span style="font-size: large">Hide/show div</span>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowHide"
    runat="server"
    OnCheckedChanged="chkShowHide_CheckedChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="MyDivHide" runat="server">


<div id="EditRecord" runat="server" 

    style="float:left; border-color:black;border:solid 2px;padding:16px" clientidmode="Static"  >

    <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
            <label>HotelName</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HOtelName" width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>First Name</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>City</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />


etc. etc. etc.
```

So, since we tagged the "div" with a id and runat="server".

So this div:

```
<div id="MyDivHide" runat="server">
   -- everything inside here will hide/show
</div>
```

Thus, the code behind can be this:

```
Protected Sub chkShowHide_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    MyDivHide.Visible = chkShowHide.Checked

End Sub
```

And the result/effect is this:

[image]

So, for asp.net, just hide and show a div, and everything inside of that div will hide and show.

For desktop and windows forms?

The approach is again similar, but in place of a "div", you just drop into the windows form a "Panel"

Drop in a panel to the form, size it as needed.
(I often have to make the form rather large to do this, since I need/want a large blank area without any controls for the panel).

Then select all the controls you want inside of the panel (to hide or show). Then cut/paste or drag/drop the selected control(s) into that panel.  Now you can simple hide/show the panel, and all controls inside of panel can hide or show.

And for both web forms or windows forms?

The nice feature is you can then have multiple sections or areas that hide/show such as a ship to "same as billing" address or whatever.

So, you wind up with this code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    Panel1.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Quite sure, even in the old VB5/6 days, the above was possible, but it been a long time.

But, either way, for web based?
Just hide/show a div, and everything inside will hide/show.

For desktop?
Drop in a panel, place everything inside that, and again a simple hide/show of the panel will hide show all the controls inside.

And for desktop, you can also "enable" or "disable" the panel, and all controls inside will enable/disable.

Hence you can use this in place of visible:

```
    Panel1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
```

## Edit: For web based?

Turns out, for web based? You can ALSO use a asp.net Panel, and both visible, and enabled works. So, for asp.net, you can hide/show a "div", but "enabled" for a div does not work, but a using panel does.

The only real "got-ya" is links - they don't disable, and you often need extra code for that case for the web, and to disable links.

So, be it for webforms, or windows forms?

Not at all sure why you suggesting or talking about all kinds of fancy pants events. Using a panel will allow with GREAT ease to simple hide/show, or enable/disable a group of controls you place inside of such panels. I can't imagine really any approach more simple then above.